# Why does a check for UIGestureRecognizer find it on iPhone OS 3.0, when it was introduced in 3.2?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using UIGestureRecognizer for the first time and I want my app to run on iOS 3.0 onwards.
Since Apple clearly states that the library is available in iOS 3.2 and later I used the following code:

```
// Make sure that Gesture recognition technology is supportted by the device SDK version
if ([UIGestureRecognizer instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(initWithTarget:action:)])
{
    [self initGestureRecognizers];
}
```

Surprisingly, when I run the App on the only target I have, that run SDK3.0, it works fine.

---

I replaced the condition to the following:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"3.2"] != NSOrderedAscending) 
{ 
    [self initGestureRecognizers]; 
}
```

I would love to get comments about it.

Thanks

Comment: zomg I love the title of this question

Comment: Are you testing on a real device with 3.0 or on the simulator? And... do the recognizers work or is the code skipped?

Comment: Hi Eiko,I'm testing on a device and the recognizers are actually functional.

Comment: The title might be funny but having a topic that is meaningful is important for both people trying to help and for future people searching with a related or identical issue.

Comment: Sorry to spoil the fun, but the question really did need a more descriptive title.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a better way to check for UIGestureRecognizer compatibility/available than the check that Tzur had implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's probably because UIGestureRecognizer was considered private before 3.2. Don't be surprised if some things are buggy or don't quite work as expected if you use UIGestureRecognizer under 3.0.

Comment: It's exactly like that. I also noticed that the UIGestureRecognizer and some of the concrete classes like `UITapGestureRecognizer` (IIRC) do exist on 3.0 but are considered to be Apple-private, i.e. not to be used by applications. They don't implement everything that is now documented, e. g. I think there was no `numberOfTapsRequired` property at `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: The following seems to be working OK. What do you think? if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"3.2"] != NSOrderedAscending) {
  [self initGestureRecognizers];

 }

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of undocumented APIs in every iOS release, and Apple does mention this.  However use of these undocumented APIs is grounds for an App store rejection.  There may well be a risk of rejection from using an API that in undocumented in one given release/revision of the OS, but documented in another, both of which your app supports.